# How to Count the number of repetitions of each element in the list in lisp?

Tags: count, lisp

I want to Count the number of repetitions of each element in the list in lisp.
e.g. (1 2 1 1 3) should give the output “element 1: three times”
Any solution for this ???

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
;Create a set from an initial input list
(defun set-from-list (lst)
    (let ((st))
        (loop for ele in lst
            do
            (if (not (member ele st))
                (push ele st))) st))

;Now iterate over the set as derived from the list, and count the occurrences, and accordingly, output the result
(defun count-in-list (lst)
    (let ((st (set-from-list lst)))
        (loop for item in st
            do
            (format t "~A occurs ~A times in list ~A ~%" item (count item lst) lst))) nil)
```

The only thing missing from this is converting the numbers to their associated string representations. But that's fairly trivial and is something you can do for yourself.

Comment: This functions perfectly working ....:) thanks a lot for the help..:)

Comment: @user2825637: Excellent! That's great to know. If it worked well for you please consider it for acceptance. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Though counting all distinct elements individually with the `count` function works, it's extremely inefficient, because it's of quadratic complexity, but linear complexity suffices to solve this task.

What you need to do is create some data structure mapping keys to values. (A property list (if there are only few distinct elements) or a hash-table would work well for general elements. If the elements are all small integers as in your example, an array would be a viable alternative.) The elements would be the keys, and their frequency the value. Then you would iterate over the list, and increment the frequency count of each value as it occurs. (Just use `0` for the optional *default* argument of either the property list accessor function `getf` or the hash-table accessor function `gethash`, and you can increase the value without worrying whether you've seen that element before or not. If you use an array, just initialize all its elements to `0`.)